# Test that detects non-stationarity of the following time series?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, stationarity, trend

Let the DGP be given as:
$$X_t\sim t^2\chi_1$$
with all $X_t$ independent. Based on simulations, an ADF test fails detect non-stationarity (i.e. it does not find a unit root). This makes sense, since ADF is a parametric test that assumes a completely different model than the DGP above.

I'm looking for some other test that will reliably detect non-stationarity of the DGP above, based on, for example, a sample of size 100 drawn at $t=1,\dots,100$.

Comment: How are you sampling this process?  This model has a definite origin, implying $t$ has an absolute meaning as opposed to the relative meaning of a time index in most time series.  Thus, details of how you collect data and how much you collect are likely an important consideration.  Also, formulating the problem like this appears overly complicated: why not work with $\sqrt X_t$ instead, whose components have half-Normal distributions and trend linearly? Indeed, "stationarity" in this problem appears to be an overly complex concept: aren't you just testing for a trend?

Comment: (Continued) Furthermore, you haven't posited any kind of alternative hypothesis: this is a *single* random process -- it doesn't depend on any parameters at all.  What would you like to compare it to?  How you test it will depend (very much) on what the alternative possibilities might be.

Comment: @whuber whether a process is (covariance) stationary or not is an intrinsic concept; you don't need to specify a reference to which you compare it. I constructed this example so as to verify whether 'parametric tests' like ADF, which are often applied without worrying about applicability, indeed capture the non-stationarity of this process, which they don't. I'm not wondering which test will correctly detect this is process is not stationary.

Comment: This is a very special form of non-stationarity.  How you test it depends *very much* on your answers to the questions I have asked.  It is now unclear whether you are looking for a way to test *this* null hypothesis against some alternative or whether you wish to study how *existing tests* might perform when given data obtained from this DGP.  Please clarify.

Comment: @whuber I'm looking for existing tests that correctly detect that this DPG is not stationary.

Comment: The question is still vague, because the ability of a test to detect nonstationarity depends on the range of times $t$ you sample.  If, for instance, you evenly sample 11 values between $t=0$ and $t=1$ inclusive then any worthwhile test is likely to detect the nonstationarity, but if you sample a million values spaced between $t=1000$ and $t=1001,$ you will still have difficulties detecting the nonstationarity.

Comment: @whuber 1) why do you say that sampling 11 pts between 0 and 1 should demonstrate non-stationarity using most tests? ADF fails for example. 2) I'll include in the question some specific sampling

Comment: The relative trend is so strong for $t$ near $0$ that just about any simple test has a good chance to identify the trend (hence, non-stationarity).  With 11 points equally spaced from $0$ to $1$ and fitting $\sqrt{X_t}$ against $t,$ OLS has a 58% chance to detect that trend.  Even with a million points from $1000$ to $1001,$ OLS only has about a 7% chance to detect the non-stationarity.

Comment: @whuber Ah yes sure, I was just confused because to me 58% is not very good still. But I understand your point.